# Plot Points within a Radius using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Database with set of specific addresses, I want to use Google Maps API to search within a radius all the addresses which fall in and use markers for them.

The data i am getting from PHP would be like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['firstName']; echo " "; echo $row['lastName'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['location'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['city'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['state'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['zipcode'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phoneNumber'];?></td>
</tr>
```

I am creating latitude/longitude from the address using:

```
<!-- Snippet to convert Address to Geo code using Google APIs Starts -->
<?php
    $completeAddress = $row['address1'].",".$row['city'].",".$row['state'].",".$row['zipcode'];
    $httpGetCallUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($completeAddress) . "&sensor=false";
    $curlObject = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_URL, $httpGetCallUrl);
    $resultGeocodeJson = curl_exec($curlObject);
    $json = json_decode($resultGeocodeJson, true);
    $volunteerLat = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $volunteerLng = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    curl_close($curlObject);
?>
```

However, i am not able to add the feature to search by radius and plot the markers within that radius.

Code to add markers is :

```
function getMarkers() {
    var contentString = "<?php echo $row['firstName'];?>" + " " + "<?php echo $row['lastName'];?>";
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $volunteerLat;?>, <?php echo $volunteerLng;?>);
    //Map Marker Object initialization
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });
    //Adding map marker content
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:  contentString
    });
    //Event listner for map marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Which address want you to search? What data are you retrieving from database?

Comment: @sabotero I am searching addresses in my DB. they are proper locations in California. Working on it here http://sewafs.org/volunteer/

Comment: So what the radius is about here?

Comment: @sabotero So i may want to select a radius/address on the searchbox and then i want only markers within radius of that zip

Comment: ok, so you have an array of coordinates comming from the database which you want filter using an address and a radius so the resulting address are in that _zone_? Is that right?

Comment: check my answer below, that could help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have already the coordinates of the address entered by user (you can achieve that with [google.maps.Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)) and the radius.

Having this you can use the `computeDistanceBetween` method from [google.maps.geometry.spherical library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to know the distance between the address entered by the user and your others positions (markers).

For the following example code I assume the positions from database are already loaded and the markes had been generated and stored in the `markers` array. And the `LatLng` for the address entered by the user has been calculated and is stored in the `address`variable, so is the radius in the `radius` variable.

```
// markers already bound to the map.
var markers;
// LatLng calculated with Geocoder from the address entered by the user.
var address;
// radius (in meters) entered by the user.
var radius;

function MarkerIsInCircle(marker){
    var position = marker.getPosition(),
        // distance in meters between the marker and the address
        distance = google.maps.geometry
                        .spherical.computeDistanceBetween(position, address);

        return radius >= distance;  
}
function UpdateMarkersVisibility(){

    for(var i=0; i < markers.length; i++){
        // show the markers in the circle. Hide the markers out the circle.
        markers[i].setVisible(MarkerIsInCircle(markers[i]));
    }
}
```

You have to call the `UpdateMarkersVisibility` method when the user click in the search button and you have finished to calculate the `LatLng` for the address he entered.

NOTE: This code has not been tested but should work fine and achieve what your want to.